# I want to make the position value move by 1 if I push the object in a 2D project

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make a block that pushes the position value by 1 in the direction of the player's push if you try to push for a certain period of time. Using the player's Ray, if an object with a layer called "MoveBlock" on the Ray is recognized for 0.5 seconds, the position value of the position block is increased by 1 in the direction that the player tries to push the block. But the blocks move like they're teleportation. So I was going to use Lerp to make it look like the blocks are moving smoothly. However, after 0.5 seconds, the position value of the block does not move by 1 but moves very finely to about 0.003.

```
Vector2 pos = (Vector2)pushBlock.transform.position + new Vector2(0, 1);
pushBlock.transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(pushBlock.transform.position, pos, Time.deltaTime);
```

How should I modify the code?

```
void Update()
{
    Move();
    Ray();
}
    void Move()
{

hAxis = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    vAxis = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    bool hDown = Input.GetButtonDown("Horizontal");
    bool vDown = Input.GetButtonDown("Vertical");
    bool hUp = Input.GetButtonUp("Horizontal");
    bool vUp = Input.GetButtonUp("Vertical");

    hStay = Input.GetButton("Horizontal");
    vStay = Input.GetButton("Vertical");

    if (vDown)
    {
        isHorizonMove = false;
        anim.SetFloat("vertical", vAxis);
    }
    else if (hDown)
    {
        isHorizonMove = true;
    }
    else if (vUp || hUp)
    {
        isHorizonMove = hAxis != 0;

        if (vUp)
        {
            anim.SetFloat("vertical", vAxis);
        }
    }


    if(moveVec.y > 0)
    {
        rayDir = Vector2.up;
    } else if (moveVec.y < 0)
    {
        rayDir = Vector2.down;
    } else if(moveVec.x > 0)
    {
        rayDir = Vector2.right;
    } else if(moveVec.x < 0)
    {
        rayDir = Vector2.left;
    }

}

void Ray()
{

    if(hStay || vStay)
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(rigid.position - new Vector2(0, 0.1f), rayDir * 0.7f, new Color(1, 0, 0));
        RaycastHit2D pushRay = Physics2D.Raycast(rigid.position - new Vector2(0, 0.1f), rayDir, 0.7f, LayerMask.GetMask("MoveBlock"));
    
        if(pushRay.collider != null)
        {
            pushBlock = pushRay.collider.gameObject;

            curPushTime += Time.deltaTime;

            if (curPushTime > 0.5f)
            {
                if(rayDir == Vector2.up)
                {
                     pushBlock.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 1, 0);

                } else if(rayDir == Vector2.down)
                {
                    pushBlock.transform.position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);

                } else if(rayDir == Vector2.left)
                {
                    pushBlock.transform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);

                } else if (rayDir == Vector2.right)
                {
                    pushBlock.transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
                }

                curPushTime = 0;
            }
        } else
        {
            pushBlock = null;
        }
    } else
    {
        curPushTime = 0;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: ok so read lerp, and time.deltatime.  time.deltatime is a tiny teeny amount of a value, so after like 10 minutes it might have moved there, if you want it in a certain time, you should a) keep note of the original position, not keep working it out, b) amalgamate the time.deltatimes so it progresses from 0->1 when it reaches 1, it will have moved to the second pos